# Scala Spark RDD : rdd.take() accepts only Integer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

```
val fileContent=sc.textFile(path)
val x=fileContent.count()/2
fileContent.take(x) // gives error x: should be integer
```

x is long. I can do `x.toInt , but what if x is too large to converted to Int?

How to get second half of the rdd?

Comment: You have more than 2 billon lines in your file? What are you going to do with half the file? (sounds like you should be sampling with `takeSample`, maybe?)

Comment: yes. it only accepts integer !

Comment: You could filter out the first half?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the elements you can use the collect method on the RDD.

If you want specifically the first half of it which is already more than Integers max size, you could as others suggested filter out the half you dont need, so basically transforming it to another rdd with less items and collect on that. Like this:

```
  val sizeOfRdd = fileContent.count()
  fileContent
    .zipWithIndex // assign an index to every element
    .filter(_._2 < sizeOfRdd/2) // filter out the first half
    .map(_._1) // drop the index
    .collect() // take every element
```

**Note**, both take and collect will move the elements in the dataset to the driver, where you might run into memory issues in case you have a lot of elements in the RDD (which I assume you have).

Comment: Why is that? sizeOfRdd is is a Long, zipWithIndex also uses Longs as indices

Comment: Thanks ! I made a mistake in  .filter(_._2 <sizeOfRdd/2) :- I forgot to add a space after < symbol

Answer (score 1):

RDD can be splitted into an array of smaller RDDs with randomSplit(), then take() can be done in a loop for each RDD.